# what does this mean for a module to have a bad taint?

Tags: boot, drivers, kernel, system, log

When looking at the syslog (dmesg), I get several of:

```
<module name>: module has bad taint, not creating trace events
```

What does this mean ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This warning appears if kernel function  trace_module_has_bad_taint() returns true; namely any of the following taint flags have been set:

- TAINT_FORCED_MODULE (module loading has been forced)
- TAINT_CPU_OUT_OF_SPEC (CPU is behaving in a way that may cause tracing issues?)
- TAINT_FORCED_RMMOD (module has been forced removed)
- TAINT_MACHINE_CHECK (Machine Check exception, possibly making lock dep unreliable)
- TAINT_BAD_PAGE (a bad page of memory has been detected)
- TAINT_USER (userspace has been fiddling around with the system that may cause kernel issues)
- TAINT_DIE (kernel is in a dying oops phase)
- TAINT_OVERRIDDEN_ACPI_TABLE (user has overridden the default ACPI tables)
- TAINT_WARN (scheduler bug detected)
- TAINT_FIRMWARE_WORKAROUND (BIOS firmware has had a workaround to make things work)
- TAINT_SOFTLOCKUP (watchdog timer has detected a soft lockup)
- TAINT_LIVEPATCH (kernel has been live patched)

The warning occurs when a kernel module is loaded and the kernel tracepoint driver is notified of this and detects one of the above tainting reasons and skips trace-pointing it to try to avoid crashing the kernel.

Modules that are just tainted as staging drivers, out-of-tree drivers and unsigned GPL modules are allowed, all other taints are not allowed.